# How do I use array_map to also specify keys?

Tags: php

Using the canonical PHPdoc example, this code:

```
<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array( 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

outputs

Array

```
(
    [0] => 27
    [1] => 64
    [2] => 125
)
```

But what I really want it to output is something along these lines:
Array

```
(
    [3] => 27
    [4] => 64
    [5] => 125
)
```

That is, I want the array_map to use the same keys as in the original array. Is there any way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$b = array_combine( $a, array_map("cube", $a));
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/s4gNV2) that it produces:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 27
    [4] => 64
    [5] => 125
)
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use array_map to rewrite keys you can use array_reduce with a closure (PHP 5.3+)

```
<?php
function cube($n){
    return $n*$n*$n;
}

$data = array(3,4,5);
$function = "cube";
$res = array_reduce($data, function(&$result = array(), $item) use($function){

   if (!is_array($result)){
    $result = array();
   };
   $result[$item] = $function($item);
   return $result;
});

print_r($res);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [3] => 27
    [4] => 64
    [5] => 125
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using `array_map`, it explicitly only maps `values`. But this'll do:

```
array_combine($a, array_map('cube', $a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `array_map` which returns a modified array you could use `array_walk` which can modify the given array. Note that the callback used by `array_walk` needs to accept its arguments by reference if you intend to change them

```
<?php    
$cube = function(&$x) {
    // Modify $x by reference
    $x = pow($x, 3);
};

$data = array(
    3 => 3,
    4 => 4,
    5 => 5
);

array_walk($data, $cube);

print_r($data);
```

This prints

```
Array
(
    [3] => 27
    [4] => 64
    [5] => 125
)
```

Comment: @Orangepill I misunderstood a key point in the poster's question. I thought `array_map` was returning an array with arbitrary keys but that is not the case. The other answers are more appropriate.